# Why do I get LNK2005 errors when compiling with /std:c++20 in MSVC++ 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

I'm trying to incorporate some C++20 features in my executable, so have enabled the /std:c++20 switch.  As soon as I do that, I start getting LNK2005 errors on member functions in a common header telling me that some of a string extension class's functions are multiply defined in both one or more libraries and also my executable.

I have a bunch of these common headers and common libraries that are statically included into my executable.  The common headers are often shared between code in the libraries and code in my executable, e.g. some string extension classes that provide some common use cases.

The string extension header contains a templated string class (the common A/W split for multi-byte vs wide character often seen on Windows) extending [the CString ATL class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=msvc-170) (don't ask me why that got settled on instead of `std::string` but it is what it is).  The errors seem to only be raised on ones where there's two versions - one specialised for `CStringA` and one specialised for `CStringW`.  However not every function specialised in this fashion are generating LNK2005 errors.

The functions are marked as inline already, and the errors go away when I compile the executable with the /std:c++17 switch instead.  MS says [its C++14, C++17 and C++20 switches are all ABI compatible](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/) so I'm scratching my head a bit.  The only thing I've found that seems remotely related is increased conformance for ['Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope' extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/cpp-conformance-improvements-2019?view=msvc-170#explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-extension), but as mentioned all these functions are already marked `inline`.

Example of problematic code:

```
inline void CStringA::FromGUID(const GUID& guid)
{
    unsigned char *szGUID;
    RPC_STATUS status = UuidToStringA((UUID*)&guid, &szGUID);
    if (status == RPC_S_OK)
    {
        (*this) = szGUID;
        RpcStringFreeA(&szGUID);
    }
}

inline bool CHscStringW::FromGUID(const GUID& guid)
{
    unsigned short *szGUID;
    RPC_STATUS status = UuidToStringW((UUID*)&guid, &szGUID);
    if (status == RPC_S_OK)
    {
        (*this) = szGUID;
        RpcStringFreeW(&szGUID);
    }
}
```

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Your sample isn't a [mre]

Comment: If you keep posting the same comment I'm sure it'll make a magical example appear.  Alternatively it'll cause a question with a lot of details and an answer to be removed and no longer be available to help others.  Creating a minimal reproducible example out of a substantial problem can be next to impossible because if one knows what is required for the minimal example, one would just fix the issue, and if I posted the 1,000-odd lines of code I dug through to get to this sample you'd be making the same comment again.  But thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Your question in it's current form is probably impossible for anyone but you to answer. It sounds like a definition of a single class and a couple of templates would be sufficient to reproduce the problem

Comment: I would have needed to provide a minimum of a header file, two source files and two makefiles/project files (one for a static library and one for the compilation target), and noted the requirement for ATL/MFC classes based off the various candidates for causing the problem, so five files and probably 200+ lines of code at a minimum at which point it would inevitably either be flagged as "not minimal" anyway or ignored because it would just be a massive code dump rather than putting all those details, as prose, in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing all that out finally made it click.

If you have a specialised templated member function, even if its template is fully defined, as of MS VC++'s C++20 compliance you now need to include `template<>` whereas you previously did not.  This doesn't appear to be documented explicitly, instead falling back to the common "Use `inline`" advice for resolving LNK2005.

Example change:

```
template<> // In C++17 this line was not needed. In C++20 this line is required.
inline void CStringA::FromGUID(const GUID& guid)
{
    unsigned char *szGUID;
    RPC_STATUS status = UuidToStringA((UUID*)&guid, &szGUID);
    if (status == RPC_S_OK)
    {
        (*this) = szGUID;
        RpcStringFreeA(&szGUID);
    }
}

template<> // In C++17 this line was not needed. In C++20 this line is required.
inline bool CHscStringW::FromGUID(const GUID& guid)
{
    unsigned short *szGUID;
    RPC_STATUS status = UuidToStringW((UUID*)&guid, &szGUID);
    if (status == RPC_S_OK)
    {
        (*this) = szGUID;
        RpcStringFreeW(&szGUID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably because on MSVC, `/std:c++20` implies `/permissive-`, and that was not the case before with `/std:c++17`. This flag means *use strict standard compliance*. I guess that on C++20 standard, but with `/permissive`, your code would have compiled.

Comment: Gave this a test and you are 100% correct.